# Laravel get latest row without sorting beforehand

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the first 7 rows of a table, and then sort these by updated_at, and get only the latest. I'm stuck on how to do this.

I've tried to get the first 7 rows using:

```
Settings::take(7)->get()
```

This of course gives me the first 7 rows in an Eloquent Collection. Now I want to sort these, preferably in the same query.

```
Settings::take(7)->latest()->get()
```

This gives me the exact same result as the previous query.
Normally I would just use a orderBy('updated_at', 'desc'), and get the first item. But this table contains more rows, that should not be considered.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,
Niels

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly, you want to get the first 7 rows in the table (not sorted), and then grab the most recently updated of those 7?

Comment: It's bad practice to assume that the first 7 rows will always be the ones you need. You should add some column to this table to identify these rows.

Comment: The first 7 records are not necessarily the 7 latest records so getting them and then sorting does not make much sense. However if you must then you can do `Settings::take(7)->get()->sortyByDesc('updated_at')`. You can also create a descending index on `updated_at` (in MySQL 8+) in which case ordering by `updated_at` should be very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Settings::take(7)->get()->sortByDesc('updated_at')->first();`

This query will get first 7 rows and then sort this collection, and then get just first item of this sorted collection.